# Unzip password protected files in Windows Active perl

Tags: passwords, unzip, activeperl

I use ActivePerl for Windows ,and i need to Unzip a password protected zip file using Perl scripting.can anybody help me to find a perfect free module to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Winzip,

http://search.cpan.org/~mbethke/Archive-Zip-Crypt-0.02/lib/Archive/Zip/Crypt.pm

Or, you would need call winzip from your perl script:
http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/18391/

Comment: Thanks for the replay,I have tried the "Archive::Zip::Crypt" But where the file get Unzipped?,I mean which directory?.Also I am getting one error like                                                                                                          error: inflate error data error
 at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 367.